# Data structure of class objects

Tags: c++

I have created a C++ program to help tracking the student’s project deliverables during the final year project life cycle. This is the UML diagram:

[image]

I have a Deliverable class and would like to use an STL data structure to:

- Host several deliverables for only one student
- Host more than one student and allow a certain student can be retrieved based on their ID

I have tried to implement this using a multimap:

```
Deliverables del(12, 15, 20, 28, 04, 2018, 1701074, "William Barker", "VR Project", 21, 9, 2017, 12, 10, 1999);


typedef multimap <Deliverables, int> DeliverableMap;
DeliverableMap.insert(del, 1);
```

Error: expected an identifier. Line:    DeliverableMap.insert(del, 1);

How could this be achieved?

Comment: `DeliverableMap` is a type not an object. You need an object just like you have with `del`

Comment: ***How could this be achieved?*** `DeliverableMap myMap; myMap.insert(del, 1);`